# How to use html form and INSERT it in to a MySQL DB (python-flask)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form>
  Event Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="eventname">
  <br>
  Sports:<br>
  <select name = "dropdown">
        <option value = "soccer">Soccer</option>
        <option value = "basketball">Basketball</option>
        <option value = "baseball">Baseball</option>
        <option value = "football">Football</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  Location:<br>
  <input type="text" name="location">
  <br>
  Time:<br>
  <input type="text" name="time">
  <br>
  Number of Players:<br>
  <input type="text" name="numplayers">
  <br>
  Minimum Age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="minage">
  <br>
  Maximum Age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="maxage">
  <br>
  Minimum Skill Level:<br>
  <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "1"> 1
  <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "2"> 2
  <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "3"> 3
  <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "4"> 4
  <input type = "radio" name = "minskill" value = "5"> 5
  <br>
  Maximum Skill Level:<br>
  <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "1"> 1
  <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "2"> 2
  <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "3"> 3
  <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "4"> 4
  <input type = "radio" name = "maxskill" value = "5"> 5
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Looks Like:

[image]

This pretty much gets the information needed to create an event.

My goal is to use the following query to post a data into my MySQL database:

`INSERT INTO Events(EventName, Sports, Location, Time, NumPlayers, MinAge, MaxAge, MinSkill, MaxSkill)`

where the values are the values that the users type into the input form.

In my `routes.py` file, where I use flask and MySQLdb, I try to execute a SQL query as follows:

```
from flask import *
from functools import wraps
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)

@app.route('/hello')
@login_required
def hello():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM sports")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    data = [row for row in rows]
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('hello.html', data = data)
```

HTML that displays the info above:

```
    <h3>Sports Data</h3>
    {% for item in data %}
    {{ item }}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
```

This successfully displays the data in the `sports` table.

But I have no idea how I should use the input form data to insert the event data into my MySQL database.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python since I work in php, but your sql syntax should be the following:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Just make sure your name field in the html form correspond with column names in the database table.

Hope this helps!